# Alter Table Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I'm trying to add barista_grade_id to the baristas table as a foreign key and I've looked every where on what syntax to use and it seems to be unanimous that this is the correct way.

```
ALTER TABLE baristas
ADD FOREIGN KEY barista_grade_id REFERENCES barista_grade(barista_grade_id)
```

I did it before this and it worked. but because of some mistakes I deleted it and redo it again, but for whatever reason it says that it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is like this:

```
ALTER TABLE baristas
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (barista_grade_id) REFERENCES barista_grade (barista_grade_id);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, does the fact that I dropped the barista_grade_id column before remaking it matter ?

Comment: Foreign keys reference primary keys. So your "barista_grade_id" must be set to a primary key. It's possible that when you added the column in again it added as a normal column, not as the primary key.

Comment: @cameronErasmus *Foreign keys reference primary keys*, wrong. [MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I just checked and it's a primary key, but it still popped this error
"check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES barista_grade(barista_grade_id)' at line 2"

Comment: Edited my answer, if that doesn't do it then I don't lol

Comment: Okay, idk how but suddenly it just works :) thanks for helping

Comment: Nice! What does the query look like @Hnasnh?

Comment: @ErgestBasha feel free to offer a solution instead of finding fault with mine :)

Comment: it's really just the brackets like u sent earlier, and I remade the table to make sure the barista_grade_id is set as a primary key

Comment: Sweet. Good luck with your project @Hnasnh!